Putting both Kafka Producer and Consumer on the same FastAPI server
I am building a real time chat with a FastAPI server that uses a websocket. I have multiple chat rooms where users can be in. I am thinking about adding a Kafka system but I am having trouble understanding how it would change my current infrastructure.
Can the Producer and Consumer be on the same server?

If so does this mean that the websocket intercepts a message, sends to Producer which sends it to Consumer and then we send it back to the frontend using the Websocket?
If not, does this mean that I need a server where the Producer is which receives via Websocket the message. Then sends it to another server where the Consumer is which then sends it back to the frontend via websocket.

The reason I want to add Kafka, is for scalability and also because I might add some processing of the traffic data.
Thank you in advance for your ideas, I am new to Kafka :)
